# Is there a way to add a variable to a constructor when fetching data?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

Basically, I'm making a statistics website where I use the Fetch API to get data and display it on my page. The thing is that the API I'm using has a hefty amount of data, all with pretty similar names too. For example, there's different type of gamemodes and could show up as:
build-casual-wins: #; archer-casual-wins: #; I am using a constructor and I was wondering if there was a way to set a variable in the constructor to make it easier?

For example:

```
    constructor(buildUHCWins, buildUHCLosses, buildCasualWS, buildCasualBestWS, buildUHCWinsComp, buildUHCLossesComp, buildCompWS, buildCompBestWS) {

    }
}
```

I'm tired of having it setup with how repetitive this is. Is there a way to just do something where it would show up like:

```
    constructor(${variable}wins) {
        this.${variable}wins = wins;
    }
}
```

Or something like that?

*EDIT*:

```
let buildCompBestWS = data.response["builduhc-competitive-best-winstreak"];
let stats = new userStats(buildUHCWins, buildUHCLosses, buildCasualWS, buildCasualBestWS, buildUHCWinsComp, buildUHCLossesComp, buildCompWS, buildCompBestWS);
```

This is how I have my other file setup where I'm calling the constructor to use the data I get from the API and display it on my page. I'm wondering how to minimalize that because as you see, I have multiple parameters in the constructor and have to call to the API for data.response.${gamemode type}.

Comment: If it were me I'd just use POJOs. Constructors are a pain

Comment: I would say that polymorphic shapes for data should be put in an object map, and the class a thin wrapper on it.  (IMO) building that kind of syntax where variable names are arbitrarily determined like that would be a bad idea for numerous reasons, from code design to optimization blocking.  You should know what your variables are when you're using them, and if you need it in the form of dynamic arrays or maps, you should use that instead.  We have destructuring now, so there's even less reason to allow that kind of problematic syntax.  And you can extend objects (including classes)

Comment: I would use POJO but I have no ideas what those are

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in an associative array/object instead of each individual record

```
let records = {buildUHCWins:"...", buildCasualWS:"...",...}

constructor(records)
{
    this.records = records;
}
```

if you wanted to have the object records as direct members you could do this

```
constructor(records)
{
    for (key in records) {
        this[key] = records[key];
    }
}
```

then you could still access `foo.buildUHCWins`

Comment: How would it work when calling the constructor from another file?
`let buildCompBestWS = data.response["builduhc-competitive-best-winstreak"];
            let stats = new userStats(buildUHCWins, buildUHCLosses, buildCasualWS, buildCasualBestWS, buildUHCWinsComp, buildUHCLossesComp, buildCompWS, buildCompBestWS);`

This is how I have it setup^

Comment: you would call it like this. `let records = {"buildUHCWins":buildUHCWins,"buildUHCLosses":buildUHCLosses,...};
let stats = new userStats(records);`

Comment: or you could just build the `records` object directly from your data response `let records = {"buildUHCWins":data.response["..."],...};
let stats = new userStats(records);`

Comment: Sorry, I'm still pretty confused on what you mean by this :3 If I do it like that, how will I specify which part of I want to show? 
`let buildUHCWins = document.createElement("p");`
`buildUHCWins.innerText = `BuildUHC Casual Wins: ${stats.buildUHCWins}`;`

Comment: to set it you would use `buildUHCWins.innerText = stats.records.buildUHCWins;` if you went with the first option or `buildUHCWins.innerText = stats.buildHCPWins;` if you weth with the second.